# regex check if there are any valid script tags in string

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to match script tag in a HTML string where there might or might not be comments.

Some examples,

```
<!-- <script>...</script> --> <script src='test.js'></script>
<!-- <script>...</script> -->
```

I only want to match the first example.

This is what i have come up with, but it does not work, any help is appreciated. thanks

```
/(<!--.*?-->)*.*<script[\s>\/]/gmi
```

Comment: Have you seen this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: yeah. not very useful. slightly different usecase, but says it can't be done in regex. i don't want to parse the script after. just need to find if there are valid script tags in my string

Answer (score 0):

Parse your string with [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to get HTML tree, then use `querySelectorAll` to count elements.

See the snippet below:

```js
var str = "<!-- <script>...<\/script> --> <script src='test1.js'><\/script><!-- <script>...<\/script> --><script src='test2.js'><\/script>";

var parser = new DOMParser();

var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');

var howManyScripts = doc.querySelectorAll('script').length;

console.log(howManyScripts);
```

Comment: thanks for a working solution. but i don't want to parse the string as it is very expensive compared to a regex match. parsing makes sense if i want to extract information out of the string, but here i just want to know the existence of a certain thing.

Comment: @xYetAnotherGamerx, if you're looking for a certain thing, please post this certain thing exactly. otherwise it's not very certain =))

Comment: the certain think is the existence of a valid script tag in string by using regex. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex:

```
<script src=['"]{1}.+['"]{1}>[.\s]*<\/script>
```

Comment: great solution, but doen't work with javascript :(  https://regex101.com/r/YAhfb5/2 i will try to see the differences between PHP and javascript regex and fixing it

Answer (score 0):

This regex works in most script tag cases

Eg. <script src="myscript.js"></script>

`/([<&][a-z]*[;]*)(script( .+[=]["'].+["'])*)([>&]*[a-z]*[;]*)([^>]*([<&][a-z]*[;]*)*(\/script)([>&]*[a-z]*[;]*))*/gi`